# How would you simplify this mapping? Array to objects

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

What would you consider to be the cleanest way to loop through `img.Group.Contents` and write out the values to the galleryImage.??? objects?

```
galleryImage.TinyImage = new myModel.Image._Img();

galleryImage.TinyImage.Url = img.Group.Contents[0].Url;
galleryImage.TinyImage.FileSize = img.Group.Contents[0].FileSize;
galleryImage.TinyImage.Type = img.Group.Contents[0].Type;
galleryImage.TinyImage.Medium = img.Group.Contents[0].Medium;
galleryImage.TinyImage.Width = img.Group.Contents[0].Width;
galleryImage.TinyImage.Height = img.Group.Contents[0].Height;
galleryImage.TinyImage.Hash = img.Group.Contents[0].Hash;

galleryImage.Thumbnail.Url = img.Group.Contents[1].Url;
galleryImage.Thumbnail.FileSize = img.Group.Contents[1].FileSize;
galleryImage.Thumbnail.Type = img.Group.Contents[1].Type;
galleryImage.Thumbnail.Medium = img.Group.Contents[1].Medium;
galleryImage.Thumbnail.Width = img.Group.Contents[1].Width;
galleryImage.Thumbnail.Height = img.Group.Contents[1].Height;
galleryImage.Thumbnail.Hash = img.Group.Contents[1].Hash;

galleryImage.SmallImage.Url = img.Group.Contents[2].Url;
galleryImage.SmallImage.FileSize = img.Group.Contents[2].FileSize;
galleryImage.SmallImage.Type = img.Group.Contents[2].Type;
galleryImage.SmallImage.Medium = img.Group.Contents[2].Medium;
galleryImage.SmallImage.Width = img.Group.Contents[2].Width;
galleryImage.SmallImage.Height = img.Group.Contents[2].Height;
galleryImage.SmallImage.Hash = img.Group.Contents[2].Hash;

galleryImage.MediumImage.Url = img.Group.Contents[3].Url;
galleryImage.MediumImage.FileSize = img.Group.Contents[3].FileSize;
galleryImage.MediumImage.Type = img.Group.Contents[3].Type;
galleryImage.MediumImage.Medium = img.Group.Contents[3].Medium;
galleryImage.MediumImage.Width = img.Group.Contents[3].Width;
galleryImage.MediumImage.Height = img.Group.Contents[3].Height;
galleryImage.MediumImage.Hash = img.Group.Contents[3].Hash;

galleryImage.LargeImage.Url = img.Group.Contents[4].Url;
galleryImage.LargeImage.FileSize = img.Group.Contents[4].FileSize;
galleryImage.LargeImage.Type = img.Group.Contents[4].Type;
galleryImage.LargeImage.Medium = img.Group.Contents[4].Medium;
galleryImage.LargeImage.Width = img.Group.Contents[4].Width;
galleryImage.LargeImage.Height = img.Group.Contents[4].Height;
galleryImage.LargeImage.Hash = img.Group.Contents[4].Hash;

galleryImage.ExtraLargeImage.Url = img.Group.Contents[5].Url;
galleryImage.ExtraLargeImage.FileSize = img.Group.Contents[5].FileSize;
galleryImage.ExtraLargeImage.Type = img.Group.Contents[5].Type;
galleryImage.ExtraLargeImage.Medium = img.Group.Contents[5].Medium;
galleryImage.ExtraLargeImage.Width = img.Group.Contents[5].Width;
galleryImage.ExtraLargeImage.Height = img.Group.Contents[5].Height;
galleryImage.ExtraLargeImage.Hash = img.Group.Contents[5].Hash;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the `galleryImage.???` objects are all the same type?

If so, declare an array for them:

```
var list = new [] { 
   galleryImage.TinyImage, galleryImage.Thumbnail, galleryImage.SmallImage,
   galleryImage.MediumImage, galleryImage.LargeImage, 
   galleryImage.ExtraLargeImage };
```

Then you can loop through them with a for-loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    list[i].Url = img.Group.Contents[i].Url;
    list[i].FileSize = img.Group.Contents[i].FileSize;
    list[i].Type = img.Group.Contents[i].Type;
    list[i].Medium = img.Group.Contents[i].Medium;
    list[i].Width = img.Group.Contents[i].Width;
    list[i].Height = img.Group.Contents[i].Height;
    list[i].Hash = img.Group.Contents[i].Hash;
}
```

Comment: I've posted my final code as a separate answer, but I essentially used your direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Functions provide a nice way to simplify repeated tasks:

```
void ConfigureImage(MyImageType img, int pos) {
    img.Url = img.Group.Contents[pos].Url;
    img.FileSize = img.Group.Contents[pos].FileSize;
    img.Type = img.Group.Contents[pos].Type;
    img.Medium = img.Group.Contents[pos].Medium;
    img.Width = img.Group.Contents[pos].Width;
    img.Height = img.Group.Contents[pos].Height;
    img.Hash = img.Group.Contents[pos].Hash;
}
```

With this function in hand, rewrite your code in only six lines:

```
ConfigureImage(galleryImage.TinyImage, 0);
ConfigureImage(galleryImage.Thumbnail, 1);
ConfigureImage(galleryImage.SmallImage, 2);
ConfigureImage(galleryImage.MediumImage, 3);
ConfigureImage(galleryImage.LargeImage, 4);
ConfigureImage(galleryImage.ExtraLargeImage, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like

```
int ix = 0;
foreach( var dst in new [] { galleryImage.TinyImage, galleryImage.Thumbnail, etc }) {
  src = img.Group.Contents[ix];
  dst.Url = src.Url;
  dst.FileSize = src.FileSize;
  dst.Type = src.Type;
  dst.Medium = src.Medium;
  dst.Width = src.Width;
  dst.Height = src.Height;
  dst.Hash = src.Hash;
  ix++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Blorgbeard's answer, here's my final code. I had to modify it a bit because the `imgType` array was going to be an unknown length. If I used a `for` loop, it would throw an "Index Out of Bounds Exception".

```
var imgType = new[] {
    galleryImage.TinyImage = new SmugMugGalleryModel.Image._Img(),
    galleryImage.Thumbnail = new SmugMugGalleryModel.Image._Img(),
    galleryImage.SmallImage = new SmugMugGalleryModel.Image._Img(),
    galleryImage.MediumImage = new SmugMugGalleryModel.Image._Img(),
    galleryImage.LargeImage = new SmugMugGalleryModel.Image._Img(),
    galleryImage.ExtraLargeImage = new SmugMugGalleryModel.Image._Img(),
    galleryImage.TwoExtraLargeImage = new SmugMugGalleryModel.Image._Img(),
    galleryImage.ThreeExtraLargeImage = new SmugMugGalleryModel.Image._Img(),
    galleryImage.OriginalImage = new SmugMugGalleryModel.Image._Img(),
};

var count = 0;
foreach (var i in img.Group.Contents)
{
    imgType[count].Url = i.Url;
    imgType[count].FileSize = i.FileSize;
    imgType[count].Type = i.Type;
    imgType[count].Medium = i.Medium;
    imgType[count].Width = i.Width;
    imgType[count].Height = i.Height;
    imgType[count].Hash = i.Hash;
    count++;
}
```